# Qual è il significato di "vomito a secco"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Una questione privata*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> L’acqua gli sciaguattava nelle scarpe, dandogli brividi che si risolvevano in convulsioni come per **vomito a secco**. Poi sentí montargli in gola un grosso nodo di tosse e allora cacciò la testa nella curva del braccio, con la bocca quasi aderente al fango, per tossire il piú sommessamente possibile.

La mia domanda è: che cos'è il "vomito a secco"? Ho cercato alla voce "vomito" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato questa espressione.

Comment: È il corrispondente dell'inglese “dry heave”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il vomito a secco è quando una persona ha i conati tipici del vomito ma non ha niente da rimettere.

Di solito lo spasmo è accompagnato da lacrimazione e, soprattutto, brividi e convulsioni dovute al tentativo di espellere il contenuto dell’esofago che ormai è vuoto.

Nell’enciclopedia Treccani alla voce [vomito](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/vomito_%28Universo-del-Corpo%29/) viene descritto il cosiddetto:

> vomito sine materia, meglio detto conato di vomito, in cui non viene
>   emesso alcun materiale;